tpm2-tss cross compile fails
i am compiling tpm2-tss for arm . i successfully and configure and    ran make , but while running make install i am facing below issue
   [/app/workspace/tpm2-openssl-1.2.0/tpm2-tss]$ make install
   make[1]: Entering directory '/app/workspace/tpm2-openssl-1.2.0/tpm2-tss'
    /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
    /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   src/tss2-mu/libtss2-mu.la src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tctildr.la    src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-device.la    src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-swtpm.la    src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-mssim.la    src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-pcap.la src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-cmd.la    src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-spi-helper.la    src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-spi-ltt2go.la    src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-spidev.la    src/tss2-tcti/libtss2-tcti-i2c-helper.la src/tss2-sys/libtss2-sys.la    src/tss2-esys/libtss2-esys.la src/tss2-rc/libtss2-rc.la    src/tss2-policy/libtss2-policy.la src/tss2-fapi/libtss2-fapi.la    '/usr/local/lib'
   libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c src/tss2-mu/.libs/libtss2-mu.so.0.0.1    /usr/local/lib/libtss2-mu.so.0.0.1
   /usr/bin/install: cannot stat 'src/tss2-mu/.libs/libtss2-mu.so.0.0.1': No such file or directory
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:12466: install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
   
   but this file exists , 
   [/usr/local/lib]$ ls -lrth
   total 149K
   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    3 Jun  5 03:39 python3.10
   drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3 Jun  5 03:40 python3.11
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   91 Sep 18 13:13 libtss2-mu.so.0.0.1 -> /opt/toolchains/foo/blabla/armv7ahf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/libtss2-mu.so.0.0.0
   
   i set the ldlibrary path and also updated .la with dependency_libs='    -L/opt/toolchains/foo/blabla/armv7ahf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib'
   but i don't understand what to do next 
   this is how i am cross compiling CFLAGS="-Wno-error=missing-field-initializers" ./configure    --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-oe-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/usr/local  (it work fine ) , then make also works fine but make install fails


cannot stat 'src/tss2-mu/.libs/libtss2-mu.so.0.0.1': No such file or directory

You have to install the tpm2-tss on your platform. That will provide the missing library for marshaling/unmarshaling (mu).
See repology for a list of distributions and links to packages. Note that distributions might package the different libraries of the tpm2-tss as separate packages.
